# Meaning of non-English singing from Diablo 2

Tags: soundtrack, meaning, identify-this-sample

I've been playing Diablo 2 enough to memorize its soundtrack, and I've heard this distinct singing from it in more than one other composition. But it's not in any language I can recognize, and I don't even know how it's spelled. None of my friends that know foreign languages could identify the lyrics, but given the genre it's probably not French or Spanish. The tracks I know of that contain the singing I'm interested in are:

- [Diablo II − #09 Sanctuary](https://youtu.be/XO056zTEDYI?t=80) @ 1:20
- [Serial Experiments Lain − #10 Cloudy with Occasional Rain](https://youtu.be/1TunrW7dRr0?t=26) @ 0:26

I'd like to know what these mean and if possible where these voice samples come from.

Comment: You have checked the soundtrack that can be found with Google? if its still not any of the listed songs, it may be Gregorian Monk chanting which is a perennial favorite of Blizzard.

Comment: It was recorded from 1997 to 2000. Are you sure it was the same Blizzard's habit at the time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, luckily, someone posted an explanation in the comments section of the video "Serial Experiments Lain - Cloudy with Occasional Rain," so go visit it. - https://youtu.be/1TunrW7dRr0

"... the vocal is a prayer to the Hindu goddess Lakshmi.
*"Prasanna Vadanaam. Saubhaagyadaam Bhaagyadaam. Hastaabhyaam Abhayapradaam. Maniganai naa naavidhai Bhuushhitaam".*

English: "I salute the Goddess, who is of smiling face, bestow-er of all fortunes whose hands are ready to rescue anyone from fear who is adorned by various ornaments with precious stones, who showers boons fulfilling the ambitions of Her devotees."﻿

Answer (score 5):

The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diablo_II_Soundtrack) for the Diablo II soundtrack indicates that the voices come from "Heart of Asia, Heart of Africa and Symphony of Voices" by [Spectrasonics](https://www.spectrasonics.net/)

A little more looking finds:

- [Heart of Asia](https://www.spectrasonics.net/products/legacy/heartofasia.php)
- [Heart of Africa 1](https://www.spectrasonics.net/products/legacy/heartofafrica1.php)
- [Heart of Africa 2](https://www.spectrasonics.net/products/legacy/heartofafrica2.php)
- [Symphony of Voices](https://www.spectrasonics.net/products/legacy/symphonyofvoices.php)

Those pages list some of the sample sources, although to match specifically what is used in those tracks would be a bigger effort.

Comment: I've done some further research. I wasn't able to get a hold of a full copy of those sample library albums, but I was able to get a hold of some 30-second audio samples of each track. After listening, I am fairly certain that the singer of the Lakshmi chants in the Diablo 2-track is the same singer as in Spectrasonics' _Heart of Asia 1_, disc 2, SINGING, "Alaap Phrases". I'm therefore almost certain that the Lakshmi chants came from that track! Here's a [link](http://www.synthmania.com/Spectrasonics%20Heart%20Of%20Asia/Images/Heart%20Of%20Asia%20CD%20listing.pdf) to the album cover.

Comment: Here's the demo sample of [_SINGING - Alaap Phrases_](http://www.synthmania.com/Spectrasonics%20Heart%20Of%20Asia/Audio/Disc%202/SINGING%20-%20Indian%20Male%20-%20Alaap%20Phrases.mp3).